# expressjs: how to extend part of layout

Tags: node.js, express

I have layout.jade, which contains  `#header #main #footer`, and `#main` contains `#content` and `#sidebar`, my template body goes to `#content` if I do `res.rend('template')`,

but now some page is special, which only want to inherit `#header #main #footer` and template body should goes to `#main`, how can I do this in expressjs, my template engine is jade.

Answer (score 2):

Jade allows you to replace (default), prepend, or append blocks. Suppose for example you have default scripts in a "head" block that you wish to utilize on every page, you might do this:

```
html
 head
  block head
    script(src='/vendor/jquery.js')
    script(src='/vendor/caustic.js')
 body
  block content
```

Now suppose you have a page of your application for a JavaScript game, you want some game related scripts as well as these defaults, you can simply append the block:

```
 extends layout

 append head
  script(src='/vendor/three.js')
  script(src='/game.js')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have a special layout template for any view you just need to call de template render with the value of layout and the name and location of your new template layout.

```
res.render('page', { layout: 'mylayout' });
```

This will render the content of page layout with mylayout for the #header, #footer and other stuff.

Comment: I'd like to reuse part of 'layout' in 'mylayout' just like header which contains user information links and footer links.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd look into view partials and organize your template so that the inner parts that will change can be swapped out.

http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-partials